# Android Random string from file after button click

Tags: java, android, random

I have some problem with Random. I need choose one line from txt file  and pass it into textview after button click (each time a different line). My code do this only one during the first click, but i want to for each button click next line is show. (sorry for my bad English) -_-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

long seed = System.nanoTime();
String newString1;


 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      valueA();
      Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

      buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      valueA();
      textGenerateNumber.setText(newString1);
  }});
  }



    public void valueA (){

            Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.question));
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

               try {
                   while (s.hasNextLine() ) {
                       list.add(s.nextLine());   
                   }
               } finally {
                   s.close();    
               }  

               Random r = new Random(seed);

               String a = list.get(r.nextInt(list.size()));

               newString1 = a.substring(2);

           }

}
```

Second problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


String newString1;
String newString2;
String newString3;
Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
.....

public void valueA (){

            Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.question));
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

               try {
                   while (s.hasNextLine() ) {
                       list.add(s.nextLine());   
                   }
               } finally {
                   s.close();    
               }  

               String a = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));

               newString1 = a.substring(2);

           }

    public void valueB (){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.answer));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

           try {
               while (s.hasNextLine() ) {
                   list.add(s.nextLine());   
               }
           } finally {
               s.close();    
           }  

           String b = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));

           newString2 = b.substring(2);

       }
```

Comment: No, i want to "reset" textView and show  new Random "newString" in textView. For example: first button click -> textView (aaa) , second button click -> textView (bbb).   aaa and bbb are the random value from text file.

Comment: how long is this textfile? I mean, if it is a very short textfile, with just a view lines, it´s possible that the Random takes the same as before..

Comment: and why You are using System.nanoTime() as a parameter for Your random?

Comment: Text file contain about 30 lines. I clicked button about 20 times and random get always this same line ? System.nanoTime()  because i had second random from other txt file and i get this same value of random. I had one file question and second answer ( question must equals answer)

Comment: I think it will be better to make a global random, set the seed by initializing and get r.nextInt() only inside valueA method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Neil Masson said, make a global Random, because like You did it, it will give You always the same result. So create a Random

```
  private Random random = new Random();
  random.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
```

and later in Your Value method, get the random. But You don´t need valueA() AND valueB(), one is enough to get the right question/answer:

```
   public void value (){

    Scanner answerScanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.answer));
     Scanner questionScanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.question));

    ArrayList<String> answerList = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>();

       try {
           while (answerScanner.hasNextLine() ) {
               answerList.add(answerScanner.nextLine());  
               questionList.add(questionScanner.nextLine()); 
           }
       } finally {
           s.close();    
       }  

       int nextInt = random.nextInt(questionList.size());

       String answerString = answerList.get(nextInt);
       String questionString = questionList.get(nextInt);

       yourAnswerString = answerString.substring(2);
       yourQuestionString = questionString.substring(2);

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your seed is a fixed value created when your MainActivity is.  Therefore

```
new Random(seed)
```

will always generate the same value.  Instead of using seed as an instance variable, use random instead

```
Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
```

and lose the new Random line in the valueA() method.

This way you have one instance of Random and use it to calculate successive nextInt values, instead of a new Random every time you use it.

**Edit:**

To answer the second question, you would be best generating question and answer together in a newQuestion() method and retrieving them with getQuestion and getAnswer. This means that your valueA and valueB will never go out of step.

```
String question; 
String answer; 
void newQuestion() { 
    int rval = random.nextInt(); 
    question = list.get(rval); 
    answer = list.get(rval);
}
String getQuestion() {
    return(question);
}
String getAnswer() {
    return(answer);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good but what should i do (look above: second problem). I need this same value from random. I get random question and random answer but  answer must equals questions for example when valueA get "question10"  valueB must get "answer10"

Comment: @Icero: I have edited my answer to address your second question.